# asp repeater and databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a problem with my asp-repeaters.

I have a link in a gridview, that opens a popup that contains additional information.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Firma Info">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <a href="#" onclick='openWindow("<%# Eval("CompanyID") %>");'>Vis detaljer</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWindow(CompanyID) {
        window.open('CompanyTest.aspx?id=' + CompanyID, 'open_window', ' width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');

    }
</script>
```

For the repeaters on CompanyTest (the popup), I have used the code from the following site: http://atul-dhiman.blogspot.dk/2011/06/aspnet-using-c-repeater-control.html because I needed the edit-functionality.

Most notably, is the source to get the data:

```
public void Show_Data()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Company", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adp.Fill(ds);
    Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
}
```

That just returns all the data I have, instead of just returning the data based on the CompanyID in the popup-window.

I have tried to replacing it with

```
CompanyDataContext db = new CompanyDataContext();
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CompanyID"]);


Repeater1.DataSource = db.Companies.Where(x => x.CompanyID == id);
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

But then my repeaters doesnt show anything.

Where does it go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code, in your page you use the following link with a query parameter named **id**:

```
CompanyTest.aspx?id=123
```

But in your code, you use the name **CompanyId**:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CompanyID"]);
```

So I think changing your code to

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

should help.

---

If you want to solve the problem based on the SqlDataAdapter, you can use the following code:

```
public void Show_Data()
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from Company where CompanyId = @id"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that. If I do that, I get an Invalid cast exception error on my databind. 
When I debug it, it says I have to make sure the number must be less than infinity or that source type can be converted to destination type.

Comment: @user3161471: can you check the href of the link in the browser? Is `id` an integer? The error points out that the value if `Request.QueryString["id"]` cannot be converted to an integer. Also check the value in the debugger to see what the page receives.

Comment: CompanyID is an int, which is stored in my database.
Id is the value of the given CompanyID - so when i click the link, it gets the value.

Comment: @dQlle: if the error occurs at `DataBind()` there might be a mismatch between the data types in the database and in the Entity model (not necessarily connected to the CompanyID column). Can you update the model from the database? I'll also provide a sample for the SqlDataAdapter approach.

Comment: It was because I had updated my database in sql, but not in visual studio. After I removed the old one and added the new, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @dQlle: good to hear that it helped. Please consider marking the answer as helpful.